# Spring @transactional is not rolling back for a RuntimeException

Tags: spring, db2

My Class is defined as

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class InteractionHistoryServiceImpl implements InteractionHistoryService {
```

Within the class I have a single method that makes 4 separate calls to separate DB2 stored procedures as follows (pseudo):

```
@Override
public void createInteractionHistory(String userId, String userChannel,
        CreateInteractionHistoryRequestPayload requestPayload) {

dao.createInteractionHistory(userId, userChannel, viewableBy,
            interactCode, systemCreationDateTime, partyGrpId,
            interactionHistoryController);

dao.createInteractionHistoryDetails(userId, interactonDescription, interactionHistoryController);

dao.createInteractionHistoryDetailsLink(userId, componentId, objectId, objectType, correspondanceType, direction, interactionHistoryController);

dao.createInteractionHistoryDetailsLink(userId, componentId, documentId, DOCUMENT, correspondenceType, direction, interactionHistoryController);
}
```

Now in the final call I force an exception in the database by passing a field width that's too big so it cannot call the proc at all. This is captured and converted into a system exception that extends RuntimeException.

I've debugged this code after the exception and it feeds into the spring framework and appears to be rolling things back.

When I check the underlying tables I can see that all the previous stored procs have succeeded and not rolled back but the final call did not succeed.

This is leaving me with inconsistent data and a headache as my understanding is that these should be handled all or nothing commit/rollback.

I've checked the stored procs and there are no commits going on in the database.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Is there any `@Transaction` definition in the `dao`

Comment: there's no @Transaction in the dao

Comment: Can you mark the transaction as readOnly as a debugging step

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider your transaction boundary. Transaction boundary is typically where your BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT / ROLLBACK statement is executed, and it's not entirely up to Spring, but could also be database implementation dependant.

Specifying @Transactional at the class level indicates every single public method of the class has a declarative transaction boundary (ie: a transaction will be started before the method executes, comitted when method finished / rolled back when exceptions occured)

In your case, it seems you did not enclose the 4 *createInteractionHistory* invocation in one single transaction -- and they are 4 separate transactions instead. Hence when the last one failed, the first 3 already succeed.

However even though you enclosed all those 4 invocation in a single transaction, it is not guaranteed that all your SQL will run in one transaction, since it depends on what code you have inside your stored proc and how DB2 draws the transaction boundary.

I suggest you spend some time on Spring transaction boundary and propagation topics -- and also DB2 transactions. [Chapter 11 of the spring manual is a good reference.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: thanks Gerrytan, the 4 calls are all within the same public method so they should all be grouped in the same boundary. What happens in the db2 database is something I'm looking into now

Comment: No prob. Yes I ran into similar problem a while ago, although it's not DB2. In my case, Oracle actually enforces implicit transaction boundary when a DDL is issue (eg: create table). Hence even if I enclosed my statements inside one @Transactional method, Oracle still closed it and openend a new one

Comment: looks like the implicit commit from jdbc is committing the changes in the stored proc. I've tested by setting this autoCommit(false) and it works as expected. I might just handle the transactions myself outside of spring. shame..